# Send whitespace with PHP socket_write

Tags: php, sockets, tcpclient

How can I send whitespace with `socket_write` in php?

When I send "Hello World", the target device recieves "HelloWorld".

```
$recieved_issi = $_POST['inputISSI'];
$recieved_message = utf8_decode($_POST['inputMessage']); // Hello World

$message = "SendMail=0,$recieved_issi,0,$recieved_message \r";
$len = strlen($message);

$result = socket_write($socket, $message, $len);
```

Comment: Did you check that it's not an error of the receiver when reading/parsing the sent message? Can you show the code of the receiver?

Comment: Protip: `utf8_decode()` probably doesn't do what you think it does, and you probably shouldn't be using it. [Hint: it turns UTF8 into ISO-8859-1 which is incompatible will all non-latin character sets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your Tipps.

I have to use `utf_decode()` because the target device uses ANSI and changing the HTML meta tag, does not work correctly.

I also found the solution. I have to put `$recieved_message` under double quotes as it is explained in the documentation of [lardis](https://www.lardis.de/) mentioned.
I have obviously skipped that before.

```
$recieved_issi = $_POST['inputISSI'];
$recieved_message = utf8_decode($_POST['inputMessage']); // Hello World

$message = "SendMail=0,$recieved_issi,0,\"$recieved_message\" \r";
$len = strlen($message);

$result = socket_write($socket, $message, $len);
```